# Squeaking round roof vent

Tags: vent

My round roof vent fan is squeaking terribly. Who can I call to fix? That is the extent of the issue, there is nothing else to add.

Answer (score 1):

Apply grease or heavy oil (30w or thicker). Stand back and admire your audacity.

Or hire a handyperson or neighbor to do the same.